# JavaScript + jQuery 3.3.1 + BootstrapDialog

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Quiero usar BoostrapDialog, como muestro a continuación:

```js
BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Example',
    message: 'Write your example here.',
    buttons: [{
        label: 'Close',
        action: function(dialog) {
            dialog.close();
        }
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

Pero me da un error.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas importando el css y javascript de bootstrap 4 y el dialog necesita bootsatrp 3.

```js
BootstrapDialog.show({
 title: 'Example',
    message: 'Write your example here.',
    buttons: [{
     label: 'Close',
        action: function(dialog) {
         dialog.close();
        }
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Pero no hay un Bootstrap Dialog para Bootstrap 4??

Comment: Por lo que veo en el repositorio del autor de Bootstrapdialog no existe una versión oficial para Bootstrap 4 pero este usuario ha creado una versión compatible: https://github.com/GedMarc/bootstrap4-dialog. Aquí más info: https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/pull/281

Comment: Yo no había encontrado nigún repositorio de bootstrap 4 para dialog, sólo he visto que añadiendo clases podías conseguir cosas parecidas. Gracias @Kiko_L por la aportación.